# Dedicated Interconnect to GCP Storage (gsutil)

Tags: linux, networking, gsutil

We are have a dedicated interconnect setup from our data center to GCP using a cloud router.

We have a RHEL linux server setup in the datacenter with a nic port connected to the public Internet and a dedicated 10GB port attached to the router that then connects to the Google Dedicated Interconnect through a Cisco router.

We are attempting to use the gsutil commands to access Google Cloud Storage without any success.

Does the storage need to be inside a VCP network? Our Google Cloud Router, by default, is connected to the us-east4 VPC with a subnet of 10.128.0.0/24.

Any assistance/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We ended up addressing some routing issues through the firewall and, as you suggested, addressing some permissions issues with the storage buckets.

We are up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage isn't inside any VPC network. I recommend you to check the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls). It may is behind a load balancer / proxy that are refusing the connection.

Also check the [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam), as the [permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) will determinate if a user has rights to list or edit the content of a bucket.

Comment: Thank you!

We ended up addressing some routing issues through the firewall and, as you suggested, addressing some permissions issues with the storage buckets.

We are up and running now.